# How can I increase input text elements' width via CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, width, textinput

For alignment purposes (I can't use an HTML table, because some rows need more tds than others), I'm trying to micromanage the widths of certain input text elements.

I've got this HTML:

```
<input class="firstblockinput" type="text" id="travelername" title="Last Name, First Name, Middle Initial" />
```

...which, as you probably noted, references this CSS class:

```
.firstblockinut {
    width: 196px;
}
```

It does nothing; travelername's width remains obstinately the same (169).

However, I can accomplish it in jQuery this way:

```
var travname = $('[id$=travelername]');
travname.width(196);
```

So how can I accomplish what is easy in jQuery using HTML/CSS?

Comment: I observed a spelling mistake in your CSS class declaration above: firstblockinut (should be firstblockinput)

Comment: In case that's just a typo while posting the question, try appending !important to your width declaration in CSS class: firstblockinput. This would help if some other CSS rule is over riding the value of width attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here..In your CSS you have

```
.firstblockinut {
    width: 196px;
}
```

whereas in your HTML, you have

```
<input class="firstblockinput" type="text" id="travelername" title="Last Name, First Name, Middle Initial" />
```

Notice the class name in your HTML as well as in your CSS

In your CSS, you have **`firstblockinut`** whereas in HTML, you have **`firstblockinput`**. Notice the missing **p**. That was the reason why the CSS wasnt working for you.

Comment: Dang, the only misspelling I forgot was "Inuit"